# IE giving error on XML code embeded with PHP

Tags: xml, php

This code works fine on browsers other than IE.

```
echo "
<item>
<link>http://www.example.com/showrssdetails.php?id=".$row[recordid]."</link>
<guid isPermaLink=\"true\">http://www.example.com/showrssdetails.php.php?id=".$row[recordid]."</guid>
<title>".$row[company]."</title>
<description><! [CDATA[".$row[desiredcandidate]."]]></description>
<comments>http://www.example.com/showrssdetails.php.php?id=".$row[recordid]."#Comments</comments>
</item>";
```

IE gives error on line 6:

An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing resource 'http://example.com/job_listing_rssxml.php...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
<![CDATA
```

not

```
<! [CDATA
```

it finds the '>' at the end there and doesn't like it.

You also need to change all '"', '<' and '>' inside your php code snippet to html entities.
You should do it this way:

```
...
<![CDATA[".htmlspecialchars($row['desiredcandidate'])."]]>
...
```

And get it back out like this:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($string)
```

Comment: Changed to <![CDATA  but still not working. Do I need to remove the >

Answer (score 2):

```
<title>".$row[company]."</title>
```

XML-injection if company can contain `<` or `&`. Use `htmlspecialchars()` to encode any text you append into markup. (It works just as well for XML as for HTML. `htmlentities`, on the other hand, wouldn't.)

```
<description><! [CDATA[".$row[desiredcandidate]."]]></description>
```

Stray space in the CDATA section, it should be `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`. Note that `]]>` is invalid on its own in text content.

Either way, CDATA sections aren't really helping you. It doesn't absolve you from the responsibilty of escaping your output: a string `]]>` in the value would still break the well-formedness. CDATA sections are a hack for hand-authoring convenience, not generally something you'd put in machine-generated XML.

Given that you have to do *some* escaping anyway for this case, you are better off forgetting about CDATA and just doing it the normal way:

```
<description><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['desiredcandidate']); ?></description>
```

(Or predefine a function with a short name like `h()` to do `echo htmlspecialchars` for you, to avoid so much typing.)

(Note: [avoid using bare-word array indices](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar). It's ambiguous, may fail in the future, and will generate NOTICEs.)